# Swift warning: Cannot find preview item for proxy

Tags: swift, pdf

I have application which generate a report as pdf file.
I can generate the pdf file, but I am receiving one warning: "Cannot find preview item for proxy:  - CalculationSheet.pdf (0)"

any advise why i am receiving this error? 
which break point can i put in order to follow the reason of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// returns the item that the preview controller should preview

-(id)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)previewController previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)idx
{
    NSURL *fileURL = nil;

    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if (selectedIndexPath.section == 0)
    {
        fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documents[idx] ofType:nil]];
    }
    else
    {
        fileURL = [self.documentURLs objectAtIndex:idx];
    }

    return fileURL;
}
```

Comment: Apart from posting a code snippet, it is advisable that you also put it into the context of the question asked and explain your solution to the problem, so the OP may learn from it. Please read how to write a [good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and improve upon it.

Comment: Code is in objective c, where should I insert this code as my code is written in swift.